# Magento 2: Downloadable file compression

Tags: magento2.3, downloadable, download-link

I am uploading size of 500mb downloadable video for downloadable product.

How can we compress the file during upload ?

I have checked the setting, no such features available from admin end.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video data is usually already in a compressed format, there might not be much to gain from compressing it further but you could try and ZIP the data into a compressed file first and then upload it.